# How to resize this chart in jfreechart, netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jfreechart

I can't seem to manipulate the chart itself. I can't change the size and `chartPanel = createChartPanel();`  keeps rewriting into `chartPanel = javax.swing.panel();`

I tried to create a method `modificarGrafico`, but nothing:

Example : http://www.flickr.com/photos/63259070@N06/6371596517/

```
public JPanel createChartPanel(){
DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
pieDataset.setValue("Toyota", new Integer(10));
pieDataset.setValue("Nissan", new Integer(25));
pieDataset.setValue("Hummer", new Integer(5));
pieDataset.setValue("BMW", new Integer(10));
pieDataset.setValue("Honda", new Integer(30));
pieDataset.setValue("Ford", new Integer(20));
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D("Ventas por Marca", pieDataset, true,         true, true);
return new ChartPanel(chart);
}

public void modificarGrafico(){
//JDesktopPane dtp = new JDesktopPane();

   this.chartPanel.setSize(200,200);
   this.chartPanel.setVisible(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);

   }
```

Comment: Is the `ChartPanel` in an internal frame, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199766/how-can-i-fix-this-code-so-i-can-add-this-jfreechart-to-a-panel/8199839#8199839)?

Comment: I can't understand nothing of what you write. What do you really want to achieve? Do you mean the resize of the panel in which the JFreeChart is contained or you mean the resizing of each portion of the chart?

Comment: I mean the panel in which the chart is in by reducing the size of the panel I assume that the chart will too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to worry about your chart size, set your Panel's layout to [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) that should help.

Comment: Just edited my answer on using a GridBagLayout instead of changing the size of the chart.

Comment: This will distort the aspect ratio of the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added your panel `chartPanel` to a `JFrame`?

If not, try this:

```
JFrame jf = new JFrame("Chart");
jf.add(chartPanel);
jf.pack();
jf.setSize(frame_width,frame_height);
jf.setVisible(true);
```

As you can see from code, you can edit the size of the frame in which the `chartPanel` is contained, with `jf.setSize(frame_width,frame_height);`.

You can just take a look to these API:

JFrame API : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

JPanel API : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html

Comment: This relies the `JFrame` having a default `BorderLayout` and a default destination of `CENTER`.

Comment: @trashgod Obviously. If the OP wants a JFrame with a specified layout, he can use a Container and invoke setLayout(), but he didn't asked for it. Also, if he wants to set the position/destination of JFrame, he can invoke the setBounds() method of the JFrame class. :-)

Comment: Indeed, more information from the OP would inform a better answer. I was curious, as a [previous] question involved `JInternalFrame`, which would work similarly to your example using `JFrame`.

Comment: @trashgod Yes, I agree that the OP should inform if he wants a better answer. I read the previous question of the OP, and your great answer, that, as you said, involved JInternalFrame. Mine is very similar to your example and I'm curious like you why the OP din't asked you for further details about resizing of the frame.